# Kafka server is getting down while pressing CTRL+c

Tags: linux, shell, apache-kafka

My Kafka server is getting down while pressing CTRL+c in my linux server.
How do I avoid that? Or is there any other *.sh file to start kafka server without any problem pressing CTRL+c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `&` at the end of your command to start kafka. It will start your process as a background process allowing you to use your console. For example:

```
#          v  Your file to start Kafka 
./start_kafka.sh -- some-parameters &
#               Add this at the end ^
```

Comment: I din't get this answer while searching.It is working fine. Thank you.